# Unexpected behavior from shared_from_this when creating multiple shared_ptr "families" over same object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Here is some example code (online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/542a060102eef161)):

```
#include <memory>

struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {};

void example()
{
    auto sharedFoo = std::make_shared<Foo>();
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> nonDeletingSharedFoo(sharedFoo.get(), [](void*){});
    nonDeletingSharedFoo.reset();
    sharedFoo->shared_from_this(); // throws std::bad_weak_ptr
}
```

What I see (under multiple compilers) is that when `nonDeletingSharedFoo` is reset, the `weak_ptr` used internally by `enable_shared_from_this` expires, so the subsequent call to `shared_from_this` fails.

I expected `nonDeletingSharedFoo` to have a completely separate ref count from `sharedFoo` since it was constructed from a raw pointer, but obviously it is still affecting the weak count of the `Foo` object's internal `weak_ptr`. I assume this is because the `shared_ptr` constructor and/or destructor do something special when the pointed-to type implements `enable_shared_from_this`.

So does this code violate the standard? Is there a solution, or is it just not possible to have multiple `shared_ptr` "families" over an object that implements `enable_shared_from_this`?

Comment: I just found this note in the cppreference [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) for `enable_shared_from_this`: "Constructing a std::shared_ptr for an object that is already managed by another std::shared_ptr will not consult the internally stored weak reference and thus will lead to undefined behavior." However, I couldn't find anything in the standard to back this up, so I'm still wondering if this is really invalid code or just a case that happens to fail given the way everyone implements `enable_shared_from_this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a gray area here: `enable_shared_from_this` is typically implemented by having `shared_ptr` constructors that take ownership of a raw pointer to an object derived from `enable_shared_from_this` set a `weak_ptr` contained inside the object. Thus later calls to `shared_from_this()` have something to return. When you "reparent" `sharedFoo` the original `weak_ptr` value is being overwritten so that it contains an expired value when you finally call `shared_from_this`.

It's possible that this behavior is forbidden by the standard, but I think it's more likely the intent that it is allowed and that the semantics of ownership are a bit underspecified in this admittedly niche corner case. The standard does note that "The `shared_ptr` constructors that create unique pointers can detect the presence of an `enable_shared_from_this` base and assign the newly created `shared_ptr` to its `__weak_this` member." ([util.smartptr.enab]/11). Despite the fact that notes are non-normative, I think it speaks to the intent of the standard.

You can avoid the problem altogether by creating a truly empty `shared_ptr` that doesn't share ownership but nonetheless points at `sharedFoo`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> nonDeletingSharedFoo(std::shared_ptr<Foo>(), sharedFoo.get());
```

This takes advantage of the "aliasing" constructor:

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T* p) noexcept;
```

which creates a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with `r`, in this case an empty default-constructed `shared_ptr`, and points at `p`. The result is an empty (non-owning) `shared_ptr` that points at the same object as `sharedFoo`.

You are responsible for ensuring that such a non-owning pointer is never dereferenced after the lifetime of the referent ends. It would probably be better to clean up the design so that you either truly share ownership, or use a raw pointer instead of the "non-owning shared_ptr" hack.

Comment: That seems to cover things (for what it's worth, the fake `shared_ptr`s were only needed to bridge the gap partway through a major refactoring and will not be present in the final design).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the get from *sharedFoo* (**sharedFoo.get()**), you get the address that is contained by the shared_ptr. So *nonDeletingSharedFoo* hasn't access to the shared_ptr and when you reset *nonDeletingSharedFoo*, you release the address memory. So the object of *sharedFoo* doesn't exist now.

Comment: `nonDeletingSharedFoo` doesn't delete the object though. It should still exist in memory.